# Can't get ReadFile to read from the file i just wrote to

Tags: c++, windows

Im writing to a file using `WriteFile`. That works fine. Its just a simple string:

> "Test string, testing windows functions".

Im trying to read from the file now and compare with the string i write just to ensure its working properly. I have:

```
DWORD dwBytesRead;
char buff[128];
ReadFile(hFile, buff, 128, &dwBytesRead, NULL)
```

But its returning false for me. `hFile` is the handle I use when writing to the file. Can have any ideas about what might be going on?

EDIT (updated from comment):

I'm getting `E_ACCESSDENIED` from `GetLastError()`. Here is how i got `hFile`:

```
hFile = CreateFile (TEXT(movedFileName.c_str()),
                    GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    NULL);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that initialised `hFile`? What does `GetLastError()` return after `ReadFile()` fails?

Comment: Examine `GetLastError()`, please show how you acquire `hFile`.

Comment: Did you seek back to the beginning of the file?

Comment: Im getting E_ACCESSDENIED from GetLastError. (apologies for the following, i dont know how to format these posts) Here is how i got hFile:   

hFile = CreateFile (TEXT(movedFileName.c_str()),                   GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

Comment: EDIT - yeah found it. Cheers for posting my response up like that. The GENERIC_WRITE should be GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hFile` has been opened for `GENERIC_WRITE` only. It needs to be opened with `GENERIC_READ` if you want to read from it as well as write to it:

```
hFile = CreateFile (TEXT(movedFileName.c_str()),
                    GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    NULL);
```

Comment: Cheers. Ive run into a further problem with this though. buff is full of just ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ. Ive never come across LPVOID before so i dont know if it is something there or what. Basically i have that string above and i want to go through a buff to test if the string and what im reading from the file are the same. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you assigned to buff[] in your example its uninitialised, take a look @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user1100102, I would ask another question for that. It will get more attention and easier to respond to that trying to solve it in comments.