# ReadFile lpBuffer parameter

Tags: c++, windows

I am using ReadFile to read a simple string that I wrote to a file using WriteFile.

Have a simple string: "Test string, testing windows functions".

Used WriteFile to write that to a file.

Now I want to use ReadFile to confirm that it was written to the file. I need to compare what I read to the original string above. To Read from the file I have

```
DWORD dwBytesRead;
char buff[128];
if(!ReadFile(hFile, buff, 128, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    //Fail
```

The function returns true so it is reading from the file. The problem is buff is full of just ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ. I've never come across LPVOID before so I don't know if it is something there or what. Is there a way to do this string comparison?

EDIT: The code i use to write to the file is quite simple:

```
if(!WriteFile(hFile, sentence.c_str(), sentence.length(), &bytesWritten, NULL))
{
    //FAIL
}
```

Comment: did you moved file pointer to start of file or reopened it?

Comment: The code you present here is fine. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to write to the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get ReadFile to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179910/cant-get-readfile-to-work)

Comment: Abyx - I didnt move any pointer. I just wrote to the file, then i try to read from the file. I assumed ReadFile would start from the start of the file. Is that not the case?

Comment: Actually that was me as well. This is a second problem, to the one asked there  that i asked in the comments and was told to ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file pointer needs rewound after the `WriteFile()` and before the `ReadFile()`. As it stands, `ReadFile()` does not fail but reads zero bytes thus `buff` is unchanged. As `buff` is uninitialised it contains junk. To rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the file use [`SetFilePointer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile ("myfile.txt",
                               GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                               0,
                               NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                               NULL);
    if (hFile)
    {
        std::string sentence("a test");
        DWORD bytesWritten;
        if (WriteFile(hFile,
                      sentence.c_str(),
                      sentence.length(),
                      &bytesWritten,
                      NULL))
        {
            if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER != SetFilePointer(hFile,
                                                           0,
                                                           0,
                                                           FILE_BEGIN))
            {
                char buf[128] = { 0 }; /* Initialise 'buf'. */
                DWORD bytesRead;

                /* Read one less char into 'buf' to ensure null termination. */
                if (ReadFile(hFile, buf, 127, &bytesRead, NULL))
                {
                    std::cout << "[" << buf << "]\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << "Failed to ReadFile: " <<
                        GetLastError() << "\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "Failed to SetFilePointer: " <<
                    GetLastError() << "\n";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to WriteFile: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Thanks, that was wrecking my head

Answer (score 0):

> The function returns true so it is reading from the file. The problem is buff is full of just ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ.

`ReadFile` only fills the buffer up to the value of `dwBytesRead`. If you're trying to work with a string, you'll have to null terminate it yourself after `ReadFile` returns:

```
buff [dwBytesRead] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use 128 as the `nNumberOfBytesToRead`, since you can get out of bounds while printing the string (or otherwise considering `buff` as a 0-terminated string). Also check `dwBytesRead` if it really reads that many bytes, and 0-terminate the string as suggested by @James McLaughlin.

Comment: With 128 it will only read in 128 characters. The string I have is only 30 chars long. I get i could have a problem with out of bounds, but if i use the length of the string for looping though then i wont come up against that problem, then i just need to check that the next character read from the file is null (if thats how it works, first time doing this stuff so not sure)